# How RoundingMode.DOWN is different from RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN?

Tags: java, rounding

How RoundingMode.DOWN is different from RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN ?  In what cases their behavior is different?

Same question for RoundingMode.UP vs RoundingMode.HALF_UP.

Comment: I suggest you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) which includes a table of examples. Look at where they differ.

Comment: This question is legit.. it shouldn't have been voted down. The Javadocs are confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html), but in summary, if you round to 0 decimal:

- `DOWN` always rounds towards 0, for example 5.9 -> 5
- `UP` always rounds away from 0: 5.1 -> 6
- `HALF_DOWN` rounds to nearest, and if midway, rounds like `DOWN`: 5.2 -> 5, 5.8 -> 6, 5.5 -> 5
- `HALF_UP` rounds to nearest, and if midway, rounds like `UP`: 5.2 -> 5, 5.8 -> 6, 5.5 -> 6
- `HALF_EVEN` rounds to nearest, and if midway, rounds to even number: 5.2 -> 5, 5.8 -> 6, 5.5 -> 6, 4.5 -> 4